# jQuery link with roll down image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-animate

I'm trying to put an .animate in a function to show more of an image when you hover over it. So far I only managed to roll down the entire div element, somehow I can't figure out how to talk to each individual image. This is what I have.

HTML:

```
<div class="social">
     <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="xxx" alt="xxx"></a>
     <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="xxx" alt="xxx"></a>
     <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="xxx" alt="xxx"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.social{
     position: fixed;
     top: -91px;
     right: 10%;
}
.social img{
     width: 25px;
     margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

javaScript/jQuery (works if I change $('.social a img') to $('.social')):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.social a img').hover(function ( ){
          $(this).animate({top:'0px'});
     });
});
```

Comment: In order to *talk* to each individual image, you have to assign those images **ID**'s.. then in your jQuery, reference those ID's with whatever effect you want to give it

Comment: could not understand what you mean by talk.$(this) is referring to the hovered image

Comment: Talk as in comminucating with the specific image. I want to write 1 function which can work forr all 3 images seperately in the div, so if I hover over the 1st image this one will move downwards by using  .animate () (right now the images are moved up in CSS).
an example of what I mean are those 2 social buttons at the right on thos page: http://mrmitote.com.mx/